# PowerBI: How do I target a value in JSON tree using power query?

Tags: json, powerquery

I need to fetch a parameter from a remote JSON and add it as a parameter to a query.

I followed a tutorial online, where the value is from a root level value, where as mine is in an array.

Example:
Tutorial JSON:

```
"value" : "/v1/projects/123456/contacts?page_size=500&vars%5BValidated%5D%5Bexists%5D=&marker=abc123"
```

JSON that my service returns:

```
"resources": [
{
  "rel": "next",
  "href": "/v1/projects/123456/contacts?page_size=500&vars%5BValidated%5D%5Bexists%5D=&marker=abc123"
}
```

If I try to get:

```
Value =  Json[#"resources"][0][#"href"]
```

it's the wrong type.

If I get:

```
Value =  Json[#"resources"][0]
```

it gets the list.

If I try:

```
Value =  Json[#"resources"][0][#"href"]
```

I get the error:

```
Expression.Error: We cannot apply field access to the type List.
Details:
    Value=[List]
    Key=0
```

How do I target the href value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try swapping out the `[0]` for `{0}`. So something like:

```
let
    json = [
        resources = {
            [
                rel = "next",
                href = "/v1/projects/123456/contacts?page_size=500&vars%5BValidated%5D%5Bexists%5D=&marker=abc123"
            ]
        }
    ],
    href = json[resources]{0}[href]
in
    href
```

In M, you use use curly braces `{}` to access items within "lists" (analogous to arrays in JavaScript) and square brackets `[]` to access items within "records" (analogous to objects in JavaScript).

So slightly different to JavaScript, where it's possible to use square brackets `[]` to look up items in both arrays and objects.

---

Details:

- For `{}`, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/m-spec-operators#item-access
- For `[]`, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/m-spec-operators#field-access